# Reading localStorage data?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm messing around with some JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out a way to read the localStorage in a way so I can have achievements go off every 10 clicks or what ever. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="css.css">
<script>
function clickCounter() {
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  var ten=10;
  var value = clickCount;
if (localStorage.clickcount)
{
localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
}
else
{
localStorage.clickcount=1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have clicked the button " +                   
localStorage.clickcount + " times.";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web   
storage...";
}
}
function clickCounterReset() {
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.clickcount=0;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You haven't clicked the button once!";
}
function Ach1() {
if (localStorage.clickcount=10) {
localStorage.setitem("GetData" , value);
alert(localStorage.getitem("GetData"));
document.getElementById("Ach1").innerHTML="Successfully reached 100!";
}
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="body">
<br>
<br>
<div id="Ach1"></div>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<div class="noLight">
<div class="pointlessbutton" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="clickCounter()">
<font color="white" size="4">+1</font>
</div>
<br>
<div class="pointlessbutton" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="clickCounterReset()">
<font color="white" size="4">Reset</font>
</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

As you may see, the actual script for the clicks works fine, so does all the HTML. However, at the bottom where it says "function Ach1()" is where I'm trying to get the script to read the data and compare it to a value I'd put in, such as 10 to then get it to spit out some HTML covered in pretty CSS and display the achievement.

Comment: Not sure what you want - there is no "?" in your question =P.  However... if I am guessing correctly something that jumps out to me as ..... odd.... is that you have `localStorage.clickcount=10`.  Don't you mean `localStorage.clickcount==10`?

Comment: Sorry; didn't make that clear. How can I get the achievement to display after ten clicks?

Comment: Also, I've tried every variation of the = / == and it just doesn't work. :/

Comment: I didn't know localStorage had a `getitem()` method. Is that intentional? According to the w3c specs there is only a `getItem()` method. Have you defined the lowercase version elsewhere?

Comment: What is the error message you receive? What does the console show?

Comment: Also pasting such code does not make a good question. You won't receive many answers and it will be down voted. Try to isolate the problem and provide a very simplistic (like 3 lines) example with a clear question. Then offer what you have tried and researched to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out a BUNCH of your code and tried to clean it up.

Also, I want to point out that I butchered the crap of HTML5, as I see you are just learning.  There are some BAD practices in this code, but for what you are trying to accomplish I think/hope you can gleam the import bits out with adopting this as dogma (I got lazy!).

Some things to be aware of:

1. JavaScript is CaSeSeNsItIvE.  So if you start calling variables "clickcounter" and then try to reference as "clickCounter" you'll run into a bunch of errors.
2. The code I provided below:  I mixed CSS in the HTML, and HTML (poor choice of tags) in the JavaScript.  I see you had a CSS file, well - yeah, you didn't post it so I didn't have access to it.  So I just took it out and added colors throughout.
3. Remember the power of `console.log("your messages goes here");`.  It's a poor mans debugger/manhole into what your code is doing at any one time.  Use it while you learn so you can see what the expected values are (FYI:  most browsers have "developer tools" -- if you are using Chrome, then hit `F12` -- this way you can SEE the CONSOLE messages (and the ERRORS in your JavaScript as you run it).
4. Don't be afraid to use functions heavily.  It's a great way to organize your code and force yourself to pick up good practices.

Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
    function clickCounter() {
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
            if (localStorage.clickCount){
                localStorage.clickCount=Number(localStorage.clickCount)+1;
                updateResults();
                console.log("Added +1 to Click Count!  New value: " + localStorage.clickCount);
                goldStarNotification();
            }
            else{
                clickCounterReset(); // Set the click-counter to 0
                updateResults();
            }
        }
    }

    function updateResults(){
        var myCounter = localStorage.clickCount;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + myCounter + " time(s).";
    }

    function clickCounterReset(){
        console.log("The reset was hit!");
        localStorage.clickCount=0;
        updateResults();
    }

    function goldStarNotification(){
        if (localStorage.clickCount == 10){
            console.log("You WIN!!! ZOMG!");
            document.getElementById("starNotification").innerHTML = "<center><h1>Successfully reached Level 10!</h1></center>";
        }
    }
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="body" bgcolor="black", onLoad="clickCounterReset()">
<br>
<br>
<div id="starNotification" style="color: white;"></div>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<div class="noLight">
<div class="pointlessbutton" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="clickCounter()">
<font color="white" size="4">+1</font>
</div>
<br>
<div class="pointlessbutton" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="clickCounterReset()">
<font color="white" size="4">Reset</font>
</div>
</div>
<div id="result" style="color: white;">Hey!  Update me!  :-)</div>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```